# What does the 'co' command do in an IRIX shell

Tags: shell, sgi, irix

I'm trying to get some legacy fortran code compiled on an SGI workstation. 
In the Makefile, the lines

```
.f:
        co $@
```

do appear. Make exits with the error

```
sh: co: not found
```

I tried googling for that program, but to no avail. Does anyone know what this could be, and where to obtain it - given the short name, I hope that it is some kind of standard tool, rather than something specific to this very Makefile.

Comment: Is it possible it stands for "check out" ?

Comment: That's exactly what it stands for, thanks! (Found it now: http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=co) - maybe you should make that an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Note that RCS has a number of commands, including `rcs`, `co`, `ci`, `rlog`.  These are not specific to IRIX; RCS was, and is, widely available, though it is not used as much as it was in its heyday, having been superseded first by CVS (Concurrent Version System) and then by SVN (Subversion — explicitly a replacement for CVS) and then by Git and the other modern DVCS (distributed version control systems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`co` is part of the RCS version control suite. It "checks out" the version of the file in question from it's "repository" (which is usually same file name with a `,v` suffix sometimes stored in an `RCS/` subdirectory).